# Generate Ipv4 address of a specific subnet with factory_boy and faker for django model

Tags: django, generator, ipv4, faker, factory-boy

Gretings everyone!

Below is a script to populate a model using faker.
Faker allows using 'address_class' argument. Specifiying address_class='a' narrows it down but only to 10.0.0.0/8. How to adjust the generator further, for example to 10.10.10.0/24?

```
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")
django.setup()
from workplace.models import IpAddress
import factory
import faker
from faker.providers import internet
faker = faker.Factory.create()


class IpAddressFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = IpAddress
        django_get_or_create = ('ip_address',)
    ip_address = faker.ipv4_private(address_class='a')


ip = IpAddressFactory()
print(ip)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ipv4_private` uses class `_IPv4Constants._private_networks` from `providers.internet`

Adjusting the `_private_networks` in `class IPv4Constants` **does the trick**

/lib/python3.7/site-packages/faker/providers/internet/**init**.py`

```
class _IPv4Constants:
    """
    IPv4 network constants used to group networks into different categories.
    Structure derived from `ipaddress._IPv4Constants`.

    Excluded network list is updated to comply with current IANA list of
    private and reserved networks.
    """
    # Three common private networks from class A, B and CIDR
    # to generate private addresses from.
    _private_networks = [
        # ip_network('10.0.0.0/8'),
        # ip_network('172.16.0.0/12'),
        # ip_network('192.168.0.0/16'),
        ip_network('10.10.10.0/24'),

    ]
```